# Laravel Auth user by IP Address

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to create a voting website. So any user who visits the site should be able to vote with or without registration. Here comes my problem - I want to authenticate the users by IP Address. I need an idea how to structure my code and view to enable this. Because I can find the user by IP and can use the `Auth::loginUsingId();` but I'm doing it in my controller. Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Answer;
use App\Question;
use App\User;
use App\Category;
use DateTime;

class QuestionController extends Controller
{

  public function show()
  {

    $ip = \Request::ip();

    $user = User::where('ip', $ip)->first();

    if($user == NULL)
    {
      $user = new User;
      $user->ip = $ip;
      $user->save();
    }

    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, true);

    $questions = Question::all();
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('home')
      ->with('questions', $questions)
      ->with('categories', $categories);
  }

  public function vote(Request $request)
  {

    $user = NULL;
    $ip = $request->ip();

    if(Auth::check()) $user = Auth::user();

    $user = User::where('ip', $ip)->first();
    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, true);

    if($user->votes_left == 0)
      return response()->json(['success' => false, 'msg' => 'You have no votes left.']);

    if($user == NULL)
    {
      $user = new User;
      $user->ip = $ip;
      $user->save();
    }

    $question = Question::find($request->question_id)->users()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();

    if(sizeof($question) >= 1)
      return response()->json(['success' => false, 'msg' => 'You had already answered this question.']);

    $user->votes_left -= 1;
    $user->save();

    $user->questions()->attach($request->question_id);
    $user->answers()->attach($request->answer_id);

    return response()->json(['success' => true]);

  }

  public static function isAnsweredByUser($question)
  {

  }

  public static function timeElapsed($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
      'y' => 'year',
      'm' => 'month',
      'w' => 'week',
      'd' => 'day',
      'h' => 'hour',
      'i' => 'minute',
      's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
      if ($diff->$k) {
        $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
      } else {
        unset($string[$k]);
      }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
  }

  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    //
  }
}
```

Comment: My home IP address changes every 3 days. Would you create a new user for me every 3 days? How about the fact that IP addresses are re-assigned? My neighbour could end up voting as me.

Comment: Then how should I authenticate the users without registration?

Comment: `voting` should be only for `registered user` only

Comment: @C2486 it's a requirement to vote without registration

Comment: If every other application that has similar functionality to yours does something in a certain way, it is generally because all of the alternatives don't work as well. You simply cannot uniquely identify a user on the internet without them providing you with at least some information, that isn't a shortfall in the design of existing systems, it is an inherent feature of the internet.

Comment: Maybe use a passwordless auth mechanism, i.e. https://auth0.com/passwordless.

Comment: You can achieve what you want using a [custom guard](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#adding-custom-guards) you will have to accept, however, that users will be able to vote multiple times by simply using a different IP. It's similar to how users can register multiple times  using a different email but much easier.

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for your reply. Votes aren't that important because it's made for the users and they won't win anything with multiple votes

Comment: may be u can try MAC address instead of IP

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj what do you suggest to get MAC address of the client ?

Comment: i have used shell in PHP to get that and it works fine for me in windows i am not sure about linux @MuhittinCokelek